# How do I receive Topic messages from a SignalR hub?

Tags: c#, azure, signalr

I have successfully created an `Azure` application that sends DbTransactions to a `ServiceBus Queue`, and then, enqueues a 'notifying message' to a `ServiceBus Topic` for other clients to monitor (...so they can receive the updates automatically).

Now, I want to use `SignalR` to monitor & receive the `SubscriptionClient` messages...and I have test-code that works just fine on its' own.

I have found many examples for sending messages to an Azure Queue (that is easy).  And, I have the code to receive a `BrokeredMessage` from a `SubscriptionClient`.  However, I cannot get `SignalR` to continuously monitor my `Distribute` method.

How do I get `SignalR` to monitor the `Topic`?

**CODE BEHIND: (updated)**

```
    public void Dequeue()
    {
        SubscriptionClient subscription = GetTopicSubscriptionClient(TOPIC_NAME, SUBSCRIPTION_NAME);

        subscription.Receive();

        BrokeredMessage message = subscription.Receive();

        if (message != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var body = message.GetBody<string>();
                var contextXml = message.Properties[PROPERTIES_CONTEXT_XML].ToString();
                var transaction = message.Properties[PROPERTIES_TRANSACTION_TYPE].ToString();

                Console.WriteLine("Body: " + body);
                Console.WriteLine("MessageID: " + message.MessageId);
                Console.WriteLine("Custom Property [Transaction]: " + transaction);

                var context = XmlSerializer.Deserialize<Person>(contextXml);

                message.Complete();

                Clients.All.distribute(context, transaction);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Manage later
            }
        }
    }
```

**CLIENT-SIDE CODE:**

```
    // TEST: Hub - GridUpdaterHub
    var hubConnection = $.hubConnection();
    var gridUpdaterHubProxy = hubConnection.createHubProxy('gridUpdaterHub');

    gridUpdaterHubProxy.on('hello', function (message) {
        console.log(message);
    });

    // I want this automated
    gridUpdaterHubProxy.on('distribute', function (context, transaction) {
        console.log('It is working');
    });

    connection.start().done(function () {

        // This is successful
        gridUpdaterHubProxy.invoke('hello', "Hello");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not do it like that. Your code is consuming and retaining ASP.NET thread pool's threads for each incoming connection, so if you have many clients you are not scaling well at all. I do not know the internals of SignalR that deep, but I'd guess that your never-ending method is preventing SignalR to let the client call your callbacks because that needs the server method to end properly. Just try to change `while(true)` with something exiting after, let's say, 3 messages in the queue, you should be called back 3 times and probably those calls will happen all together when your method exits.

If that is right, then you can move to something different, like dedicating a specific thread to consuming the queue and having callbacks called from there usning `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext`. Probably better, you could try a different process consuming the queue and doing `HTTP POST` to your web app, which in turns broadcasts to the clients.

Comment: I will try that.  However, I cant even get SignalR to continuously Persist, much less, even call that particular message (very frustrating).  Part of the problem is most online examples use a previous version of SignalR...and I am using "version 2.0.3".

Comment: Official docs @ http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20 is quite extensive and all about 2.0. Your comment in code *This works great from the client, but I have to Invoke it.* makes me thing maybe you are missing some basic background... That Hello method must be invoked from the client, hub methods are meant to be called like that. Same for Distribute, it does not run "like that", you have to invoke it explicitly.